# sending different 'Content-Type' for each single input param one file and other data params

Tags: python-requests

Is there any way to send each different 'Content-Type' in the multipart-form data for each single input param

e.g.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=q235Ht2tTWJhuFmC8sJxbQ7YGU7FwQafcZd8B
Accept-Charset: utf-8
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="creative_id"
"Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1”
…
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“file_role""
"Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1”
…
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename""
"Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="advertise_A.png"
"Content-Type: image/x-png"
```

For the whole request, the header will be 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
but for its params like creative_id and file_role, 
I would like to send Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1 
and for the file itself Content-Type: image/x-png

I tried this in two ways, but it doesnt work:

```
headers = {'Content-Type':'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1'} 
files = {'file': open(asset_file, 'rb')}
and then in POST (url, files=files, headers=headers, params=values)
```

OR

```
files = {'file1': (open(asset_file, 'rb'), 'image/x-png'), 'creative_id': (1727968, 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1'), 'file_role': ('PRIMARY', 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1')}
and then in POST (url, files=files)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close with the second example. If you provide a dict with tuples as its value, the tuples have this form:

```
(filename, file object or content, [content type], [headers])
```

where the `content type` and `headers` fields are optional.

This means you want to do this:

```
files = {'file': ('advertise_A.png', open(asset_file, 'rb'), 'image/x-png'), 'creative_id': ('', '1727968', 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1'), 'file_role': ('', 'PRIMARY', 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1'), 'Filename': ('', 'advertise_A.png', 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Doing the above with a file that contains only the string `basic_test`, I get the following result:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=82c444831d6a450ba5c4ced2e1cc7866

--82c444831d6a450ba5c4ced2e1cc7866
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="creative_id"
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1

1727968
--82c444831d6a450ba5c4ced2e1cc7866
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_role"
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1

PRIMARY
--82c444831d6a450ba5c4ced2e1cc7866
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="advertise_A.png"
Content-Type: image/x-png

basic_test
--82c444831d6a450ba5c4ced2e1cc7866
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1

advertise_A.png
--82c444831d6a450ba5c4ced2e1cc7866--
```